# Post File name variable using tcpsend autoit

Tags: autoit

I need to know how to post file name variable to desired one instead of "upload.zip"

i know how to automate file name using php only but required autoit to post variable of file name using tcpsend method

Thanks

PHP code:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
copy($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], "upload.zip");
?>
```

Autoit code:

```
ConsoleWrite(_PHPupload('192.168.1.2', _OSmacros(), 89, '/upload/index.php', 'application/zip') & @CRLF)

    Func _PHPupload($pIP, $pMacros, $pPort, $phpPath, $pContent)
        If FileExists($pFile) = 0 Then Return SetError(1, 1, '')
        $pTcpc = TCPConnect($pIP, $pPort)
        If @error Then Return SetError(1, 2, '')
        Local $pBound = "-----" & Random(10000000, 99999999, 1)
        Local $pData1 = "--" & $pBound & @CRLF
        $pData1 &= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload";  filename="' & $pFile & '"' & @CRLF & 'Content-Type: ' & $pContent & @CRLF & @CRLF
        Local $pData2 = @CRLF & "--" & $pBound & @CRLF & 'Content-Disposition: form-data ;name="test"' & @CRLF & @CRLF & "variable" & @CRLF
        $pData2 &= "--" & $pBound & "--" & @CRLF & @CRLF
        Local $pHeader = 'POST ' & $phpPath & ' HTTP/1.1' & @CRLF
        $pHeader &= 'Host: ' & $pIP & @CRLF
        $pHeader &= 'User-Agent: ' & $pMacros & @CRLF
        $pHeader &= 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=' & $pBound & @CRLF
        $pHeader &= 'Content-Length: ' & (StringLen($pData1) + StringLen($pData2) + FileGetSize($pFile)) & @CRLF & @CRLF
        Local $pFopen = FileOpen($pFile, $FO_READ)
        If $pFopen = -1 Then Return SetError(1, 3, '')
        Local $sFread = FileRead($pFopen)
        TCPSend($pTcpc, $pHeader & $pData1 & $sFread & $pData2)
        If @error Then Return SetError(1, 4, '')


        Local $pBuffer = ""

        While 1
            $pBuffer &= TCPRecv($pTcpc, 1024)
            If @error Then
                Return SetError(1, 5, '')
            Else
                ExitLoop
            EndIf
        WEnd

        MsgBox(64, "", $pBuffer)

    EndFunc   ;==>_PHPupload
```

Answer (score 0):

> $pFile is not declared, but even if it is, it wont work because its a
>   filepath and you are sending it as a filename at

```
filename="' & $pFile
```

This should work:

```
ConsoleWrite(_PHPupload('192.168.1.2', _OSmacros(), 89, '/upload/index.php', 'application/zip', "c:\somedir", "somefile.zip") & @CRLF)

    Func _PHPupload($pIP, $pMacros, $pPort, $phpPath, $pContent, $pFilePath, $pFileName)
        $pFile = $pFilePath & "\" & $pFileName
        If FileExists($pFile) = 0 Then Return SetError(1, 1, '')
        $pTcpc = TCPConnect($pIP, $pPort)
        If @error Then Return SetError(1, 2, '')
        Local $pBound = "-----" & Random(10000000, 99999999, 1)
        Local $pData1 = "--" & $pBound & @CRLF
        $pData1 &= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload";  filename="' & $pFileName & '"' & @CRLF & 'Content-Type: ' & $pContent & @CRLF & @CRLF
        Local $pData2 = @CRLF & "--" & $pBound & @CRLF & 'Content-Disposition: form-data ;name="test"' & @CRLF & @CRLF & "variable" & @CRLF
        $pData2 &= "--" & $pBound & "--" & @CRLF & @CRLF
        Local $pHeader = 'POST ' & $phpPath & ' HTTP/1.1' & @CRLF
        $pHeader &= 'Host: ' & $pIP & @CRLF
        $pHeader &= 'User-Agent: ' & $pMacros & @CRLF
        $pHeader &= 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=' & $pBound & @CRLF
        $pHeader &= 'Content-Length: ' & (StringLen($pData1) + StringLen($pData2) + FileGetSize($pFile)) & @CRLF & @CRLF
        Local $pFopen = FileOpen($pFile, $FO_READ)
        If $pFopen = -1 Then Return SetError(1, 3, '')
        Local $sFread = FileRead($pFopen)
        TCPSend($pTcpc, $pHeader & $pData1 & $sFread & $pData2)
        If @error Then Return SetError(1, 4, '')


        Local $pBuffer = ""

        While 1
            $pBuffer &= TCPRecv($pTcpc, 1024)
            If @error Then
                Return SetError(1, 5, '')
            Else
                ExitLoop
            EndIf
        WEnd

        MsgBox(64, "", $pBuffer)

    EndFunc   ;==>_PHPupload
```